# Creating Color and Text Graph in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a graph in R that is colored by group and has text by sex.
The group variable is 0s and 1s, and the sex variable is 0s and 1s.

Here is my code. It has to be in base R, not ggplot2.

```
df$group <- factor(df$group)
df_group <- as.vector(df$group)

cols3 <- factor(x = df_group,
               levels = c("control", "trial group"),
               labels = c("black", "blue"))

plot(x = df$pk1,
y = df$pk5,
xlab = "Base Headache Severity Rating",
ylab = "1-year Headache Severity Rating",
main = "Headache Severity Ratings",
type = "n")

text(x= df$pk1,
     y = df$pk5,
     labels = df$sex,
     col = cols3)

legend(x = "bottomright",
legend = c("control", "trial group"),
col = c("black", "blue"),
pch = 15, pt.cex = 1.5)
```

I've tried everything and cannot get it to work! Help!

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky without some sample data, but essentially you need to pass a vector of colors to the `col` argument of text, not a factor vector. Since the group is coded as 0 and 1, then adding 1 to this will produce a vector of 1s and 2s - this could be used to subset the vector `c("black", "blue")` to get the correct vector of colours:

```r
plot(x = df$pk1,
y = df$pk5,
xlab = "Base Headache Severity Rating",
ylab = "1-year Headache Severity Rating",
main = "Headache Severity Ratings",
type = "n")

text(x= df$pk1,
     y = df$pk5,
     labels = df$sex,
     col = c("black", "blue")[df$group + 1])

legend(x = "bottomright",
legend = c("control", "trial group"),
col = c("black", "blue"),
pch = 15, pt.cex = 1.5)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(group = rep(0:1, each = 10),
                 sex   = rep(0:1, 10),
                 pk1   = rep(1:10, 2),
                 pk5   = c(3L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 8L, 
                           1L, 10L, 2L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L))
```